# Why does popen() invoke a shell to execute a process?

Tags: c, linux, sh, popen

I'm currently reading up on and experimenting with the different possibilities of running programs from within C code on Linux. My use cases cover all possible scenarios, from simply running and forgetting about a process, reading from *or* writing to the process, to reading from *and* writing to it.

For the first two, `popen()` is very easy to use and works well. I understand that it uses some version of `fork()` and `exec()` internally, then invokes a shell to actually run the command.

For the third scenario, `popen()` is not an option, as it is unidirectional. Available options are:

- Manually `fork()` and `exec()`, plus `pipe()` and `dup2()` for input/output
- `posix_spawn()`, which internally uses the above as need be

What I noticed is that these can achieve the same that `popen()` does, but we can completely avoid the invoking of an additional `sh`. This sounds desirable, as it seems less complex.

However, I noticed that even [examples on `posix_spawn()`](https://www.systutorials.com/37124/a-posix_spawn-example-in-c-to-create-child-process-on-linux/) that I found on the Internet do invoke a shell, so it would seem there must be a benefit to it. If it is about parsing command line arguments, `wordexp()` seems to do an equally good job.

What is the <del>reason behind</del> benefit of invoking a shell to run the desired process instead of running it directly?

---

**Edit**: I realized that my wording of the question didn't precisely reflect my actual interest - I was more curious about the *benefits* of going through `sh` rather than the (historical) *reason*, though both are obviously connected, so answers for both variations are equally relevant.

Comment: How would you handle `popen("cmd1; cmd2 | grep foo")` without invoking shell? You'd have to basically implement shell inside standard library.

Comment: @el.pescado good point, also mentioned in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884997/3316645). In practice, I would advice my users (the commands ultimately come from the user) to wrap such things in an executable bash script, then run _that_ through my program. That should work, I suppose. But definitely an important difference between using the shell and not using it.

Comment: I've often thought it would have been better for `system()`, `popen()` etc. to accept `execl()`-style argument lists, and only start a shell if you ask for that explicitly (e.g. `popen(get_shell(), "-c", "$commands")`).  But it is the way it is, for good or bad.  OTOH, you're in luck, because you can write your own function to do what you want, and you can read the implementations of `popen()` to crib from them.

Comment: @TobySpeight agreed. I ended up using `popen()` for where I only need unidirectional communication, `posix_spawn()` to start and forget about a process and wrote my own function for bidirectional communication. All seems to work well so far and it helped me to get a better understanding of the functions involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoking a shell allows you to do all the things that you can do in a shell.
For example,

```
FILE *fp = popen("ls *", "r");
```

is possible with `popen()` (expands all files in the current directory).
Compare it with:

```
execvp("/bin/ls", (char *[]){"/bin/ls", "*", NULL});
```

You can't exec `ls` with `*` as argument because `exec(2)` will interpret `*` literally.

Similarly, pipes (`|`), redirection (`>`, `<`, ...), etc., are possible with `popen`.

Otherwise, there's no reason to use `popen` if you don't need shell - it's unnecessary. You'll end up with an extra shell process and all the things that can go wrong in a shell go can wrong in your program (e.g., the command you pass could be incorrectly interpreted by the shell and a common security issue). [`popen()` is designed that way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html). `fork` + `exec` solution is cleaner without the issues associated with a shell.

Comment: Regarding expansion, that did occur to me, but that's why I mentioned `wordexp()` - it would expand the `*` similar to how the shell would, right? The pipes, however, are indeed a good point.

Comment: Then you'll endup re-implementing a shell ;-)

Comment: True. However, it still saves on the additional `sh` process, which I find quite desirable. But that obviously depends on the use case and also on taste.

Comment: See `popen` as a convenience. It's designed (and *required* by POSIX) to invoke a shell. So, it'll and the standard `popen` function isn't going to change its behaviour. If your requirement is different, you can custom implement a custom one. But if you don't need shell functionality, then it's always better to use fork+exec.

Answer (score 4):

The glib answer is because the The POSIX standard ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html ) says so. Or rather, it says that it should behave as if the command argument is passed to /bin/sh for interpretation.

So I suppose a conforming implementation could, in principle, also have some internal library function that would interpret shell commands without having to fork and exec a separate shell process. I'm not actually aware of any such implementation, and I suspect getting all the corner cases correct would be pretty tricky.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, I wonder what's the reason behind the standard? Trying some simple programs with both, `popen()` and `posix_spawnp()`, seems to yield identical results so far, just that I save one additional `sh` process with the latter. Even bash scripts are being executed nicely, as is indicated by the [manpage of `execve`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). What kind of corner cases might I run into when doing it this way? Should one always go through `sh`?

Comment: Well, the shell interpreter can do all kinds of stuff such as globbing (*). If you don't need that, by instead using fork+exec (or posix_spawn) you can indeed save one extra fork+exec.

Comment: @domsson : the reason behind this standard is existing practices. This mechanism was often used for email and lpd filters, allowing the admins to add or edit the filters *without compilation*

Answer (score 3):

[The 2004 version of the POSIX `system()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) has a rationale that is likely applicable to `popen()` as well.  Note the stated restrictions on `system()`, especially the one stating "that the process ID is different":

> ***RATIONALE***
>
> ...
>
> There are three levels of specification for the system() function. The
>   ISO C standard gives the most basic. It requires that the function
>   exists, and defines a way for an application to query whether a
>   command language interpreter exists. It says nothing about the command
>   language or the environment in which the command is interpreted.
>
> IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 places additional restrictions on system(). It
>   requires that if there is a command language interpreter, the
>   environment must be as specified by fork() and exec. This ensures, for
>   example, that close-on- exec works, that file locks are not inherited,
>   and that the process ID is different. It also specifies the return
>   value from system() when the command line can be run, thus giving the
>   application some information about the command's completion status.
>
> Finally, IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 requires the command to be interpreted
>   as in the shell command language defined in the Shell and Utilities
>   volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.

Note the multiple references to the "ISO C Standard".  [The latest version of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) requires that the command string be processed by the system's "command processor":

> **7.22.4.8  The `system` function**
>
> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> int system(const char *string);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> If `string` is  a  null  pointer,  the `system` function  determines 
>   whether  the  host environment  has  a command  processor. If `string`
>   is  not  a  null  pointer,  the `system` function  passes  the  string
>   pointed  to  by `string` to  that  command  processor  to  be executed
>   in a manner which the implementation shall document; this might then
>   cause the program calling `system` to behave in a non-conforming
>   manner or to terminate.
>
> **Returns**
>
> If  the  argument  is  a  null  pointer,  the `system` function 
>   returns  nonzero  only  if  a command  processor  is  available.   If
>   the  argument  is  not  a  null  pointer, and  the `system` function
>   does return, it returns an implementation-defined value.

Since the C standard requires that the systems "command processor" be used for the `system()` call, I suspect that:

1. Somewhere there's a requirement in POSIX that ties `popen()` to the `system()` implementation.
2. It's much easier to just reuse the "command processor" entirely since there's also a requirement to run as a separate process.

So this is the glib answer twice-removed.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer. I realize now that I should have asked _"What's the benfit [...]"_ instead of _"What's the reason [...]"_, but this is equally interesting and relevant.

Comment: @domsson I suspect the benefit is "that's how it was done prior to standardization, and we didn't want to break things".